# Piezoelectric igniter not producing spark

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I was doing some work on my residential gas lines which required turning off the gas at the main. After the work was complete, I turned on the gas at the main and initiated the process to re-light the gas water heater pilot.<sup>1</sup> I did get the pilot to re-light (saw the pilot light through the window), but I was not sure that I did it correctly (not sure why). So, I turned off the gas and let it air out for 10 minutes. I then returned to redo the process, but then the piezo igniter was not producing a spark. Coincidentally, when the plumber was here a few weeks earlier installing gas line, he too had a bit of difficulty getting the piezo to ignite the pilot.

Since I'm not a fan of cold showers, I wanted to just buy a new water heater since this is ten years old, but I figure, in the spirit of DIY home improvement, why not just replace the faulty component and have some spare change left over.

For the State GS640YBRS natural gas water heater, what is the more common cause of the piezo igniter not producing a spark?

1. A faulty piezo igniter (9003407005)

[image: Piezo igniter - 9006143015]

2. A faulty natural gas burner assembly (9003379005)

[image: Natural gas burner assembly - 9003379005]

Or other?

---

<sup>1</sup> State GS640YBRS natural gas water heater, 40-gallon, atmospheric vent

Comment: If the piezo isn't producing a spark, it's either faulty or grounded on something. Is there a reason to suspect the burner assembly?

Comment: Don't newer models dispense with the pilot, just using the igniter every time heat's demanded? That saves on gas usage; but probably not enough to warrant throwing out an otherwise solid unit.

Comment: You can also light it with a [long match like this](http://www.acehardware.com/product/index.jsp?productId=10801385&KPID=8856358&cid=CAPLA:G:Shopping_-_Hearth_Products_&_Accs_-_New=&pla=pla_8856358&k_clickid=fa0fb43a-ac6f-48c4-99b9-9816966617ff) I keep a box next the furnace and water heater to make relighting easier.